# Need to split a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a below data in a csv ( it is a comma separated file,first line is column headers)

```
ID,ENV,dictionary_column
35702,name1,"{'Employee': 1.56, 'IC': 1.18}"
35700,nam22,"{'Quota': 3.06, 'ICS': 0.37}"
11765,quotation,"{'02 WSS': 12235, '44 HR Part': 485, '333 CNTL':1}"
22345,gamechanger,"{'02 Employee's': 5.1923513, '04 Participant': 0.167899}"
22345,supporter,"{'0': '31', 'Table': '5', 'NewAssignee': '1', 'Result': '5'}"
```

The column dictionary_column contains multiple key-value pairs which I need to separate out and join with remaining columns

Desired output ( either csv or dataframe):

```
ID      ENV        dictionary_key       dictionary_value
35702   name1      Employee abc         1.56
35702   name1      IC                   1.18
35700   nam22      Quotation            3.06
35700   nam22      IC newer             0.37
35700   nam22      newmeansnew          0.001
11765   quotation  02 WSS               12235
11765   quotation  44 HR Part           485
11765   quotation  333 CNTL             1
........ .......   ...                  ... (likewise)
```

(Don't mind spaces in the output, added for formatting or readability)

```
The dictionary_column values example :
```

"{'0': '31', 'Table': '5', 'NewAssignee': '1', 'Result': '5'}"

```
this is the trouble part
```

I tried few things from ast function and also tried by converting the dict to json by json.normalize
but with 10k rows any method isn't giving correct results

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("the.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f]

vals = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split("   ") # file seems separated by 3 spaces or \t, adjust if needed
    for k, v in json.loads(parts[2].replace("'", "\"")).items(): # json.loads() excepts values enclosed in double quote, not single
        vals.append([parts[0], parts[1], k, v])

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=["ID", "ENV", "dictionary_key", "dictionary_value"])
```

---

```
      ID    ENV dictionary_key  dictionary_value
0  35702  name1   Employee abc             1.560
1  35702  name1             IC             1.180
2  35700  nam22      Quotation             3.060
3  35700  nam22       IC newer             0.370
4  35700  nam22    newmeansnew             0.001
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/daf66cf570)

Comment: Its a csv so it has ,(comma) separated values when i open it in notepad++ .  So if I adjust parts = line.split(",") - this is causing trouble as the dictionary itself has another commas separated values - raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)

Comment: I can only work with the example that you used on your question and you may want to updated it with the actual data contained on the file. It does make sense otherwise.

Comment: If you want help, you've to do better than providing a badly formatted comment example. Please update your **question** with the first 5 lines, or so, **exactly** like they are on the csv file (including the headers) and one line containing quotes.

Comment: Updated the question same as actual data. sorry, new to stackoverflow, wasn't familiar with the edit flow of the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution for required output

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("the.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f]
 
vals = ""
valLst = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(",") # file seems separated by 3 spaces or \t, adjust if needed

    flag = False
    nextParts = ""
    for part in parts: 
        if part.startswith('\"'): 
            flag = True
        if flag:
            nextParts = nextParts +','+ part
           

    nextParts = nextParts.strip(',')
    nextParts = nextParts.strip('"')
    nextParts = nextParts.replace('\'', "\"")
    
   
    for k, v in json.loads(nextParts).items(): # json.loads() excepts values enclosed in double quote, not single
        valLst.append([parts[0], parts[1], k, v])


df = pd.DataFrame(valLst, columns=["ID", "ENV", "dictionary_key", "dictionary_value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

## More complete solution

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("the2.csv") as f:
    next(f)
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f]

vals = ""
valLst = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(",") # file seems separated by 3 spaces or \t, adjust if needed

    flag = False
    nextParts = ""
    for part in parts: 
        if part.startswith('{') and part.endswith('}'):
            nextParts = nextParts +','+ part
            flag = False
        elif part.startswith('\"'):
            flag = True
        elif part.endswith('\"'):
            nextParts = nextParts +','+ part
            flag = False
        else:
            pass

        if flag:
            nextParts = nextParts +','+ part


    nextParts = nextParts.strip(',')
    nextParts = nextParts.strip('"')
    nextParts = nextParts.replace('\'', "\"")

    if nextParts.startswith('{"'):
        pass
    else:
        copyparts = nextParts.split(":")
        otherparts = ""

        for copypart in copyparts: 
            if copypart.startswith('{'):
                otherparts = otherparts + copypart
                otherparts = otherparts.replace('{', '{"')
                otherparts = otherparts + "\" :"
            else:
                otherparts = otherparts + "\"" + copypart.strip(' ')
                otherparts = otherparts.replace('}', '"}')

        otherparts = otherparts.strip('"')
        otherparts = otherparts.replace('\'', "\"")
        nextParts = otherparts

    for k, v in json.loads(nextParts).items(): # json.loads() excepts values enclosed in double quote, not single
        valLst.append([parts[0], parts[1], k, v])


df = pd.DataFrame(valLst, columns=["ID", "ENV", "dictionary_key", "dictionary_value"])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.dictionary_column.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(eval(x.strip('"')))).T.reset_index()
    dd1.columns=["dictionary_key","dictionary_value"]
    return dd.sql().join(dd1.sql(),how="left",condition='1=1').select("ID,ENV,dictionary_key,dictionary_value").df()

df1.groupby(level=0,as_index=0,group_keys=0).apply(function1)

：

     ID          ENV dictionary_key dictionary_value
0  35702        name1       Employee             1.56
1  35702        name1             IC             1.18
0  35700        nam22          Quota             3.06
1  35700        nam22            ICS             0.37
0  11765    quotation            WSS            12235
1  11765    quotation         HRPart              485
2  11765    quotation           CNTL                1
0  22345  gamechanger      Employees         5.192351
1  22345  gamechanger    Participant         0.167899
0  22345    supporter             a0               31
1  22345    supporter          Table                5
2  22345    supporter    NewAssignee                1
3  22345    supporter         Result                5
```